# Get a Set (or Collection) of all classes in java.lang package

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compilation, java.lang.class

I am writing a compiler for Java, and would like to implicitly import `java.lang` package to all source files (This is what most Java compilers that I know of do).

To do that, I need to somehow obtain either a set of all classes (ie.,`Set<Class<?>>`) or a set of all qualified names (ie., `Set<String>`) of all classes in the package.

I've looked at the reflections API from [this page](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/), but the structure of my project (and other factors) make it a less-than-suitable candidate.

So I'm wondering whether there is any other way to obtain such classes (other than hard-coding the thing, of course!)? The fact that `java.lang` is the most popular package in Java kind of suggests that there should be some way(s).

Comment: *"make it a less - than -suitable candidate"*  Why, specifically?

Comment: Note that your compiler will also need to implicitly import the default (no name) package and the package the source file is in.

Comment: Well, to start off, the requirement is that the compiler has to be able to compile itself, and my compiler is not handling generic very well (let alone reflections and all that). But suppose we ignored that for a moment, in practice, when I added the jar downloaded from the site along with its dependencies (Guava and slf4j) to the build file, the project still doesn't run correctly, and I keep getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.Predicates`

Comment: @AndrewThompson (See above, sorry I forgot to tag)

Comment: @PaulBellora That part is already handled properly. What I need here is to add a little 'feature', that is, to have `java.lang.*` implicitly imported

Comment: @user1801813 Okay, interesting.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    String path = Object.class.getResource("Object.class").getPath().replace("!/java/lang/Object.class", "");
    ZipFile z = new ZipFile(new File(new URI(path)));
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e =z.entries();
    Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
    while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String n = e.nextElement().getName();
        if (n.matches("java/lang/\\w+\\.class")) {
            s.add(n);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user1801813 [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html).

Comment: It's java.util.zip package

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if it is just my machine that is badly configured, but `rt.jar` cannot be opened. And I am not inclined to think that packing the file together with the compiler is a wise thing to do ?

Comment: Here is all I have in my `java.home\lib`:  `
ct.sym  dt.jar  ir.idl  jconsole.jar orb.idl  sa-jdi.jar tools.jar
`

Comment: if you are on mac then it is classes.jar and path probably will be like ("java.home") + "/../Classes/classes.jar

Comment: i fixed the way to get the path in the answer, hope it will help